# To find file exist in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an issue with scripted jenkins pipeline. I need to check if the directory has specific file in it. But the thing is filename gets changed everyday. I need to filter it based on file type.

I tried with `fileExists()`. It doesn't gets into the if loop.

````
   if(fileExists('*.txt'){
      //do something
    } else{
    //do something
    }
} ```
any help will be really appreciated.
````

Comment: I believe `fileExists` needs an exact file name, not a shell glob. But if you're going to use a glob, you could consider using `sh` (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script).

Comment: There is no [tag:java] here.